# Algorithm for b-matching on bipartite graph

Tags: graphs, matching

I have a bipartite graph, where I want to assign nodes in Left set to Right set of nodes. There is a "b" constraint, which limits the maximum possible node degrees on the Right set.
Since it is a classic problem, I expected to find a lot of algorithms on it, but was not successful. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Thanks, I see you wrote an algorithm to solve it, can you give me the reference to read more about that?

Comment: You can check a  "Combinatorial Optimization" book (I would suggest Bernhard Korte's book or Alexander Schrijver's book).